# How do I use BigNumber values in Hardhat tests?

Tags: testing, hardhat, bignumber

I'm using Hardhat with TypeScript/Ethers/Chai. I can't find a way to test BigNumber values.

For example, `expect(someBigNumber).to.be.equal.to.(otherBigNumber)` will (understandably) throw an error like this one: `AssertionError: expected 9999969797040000000000 to be a number or a date`.

I installed chai-bn and followed the example [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chai-bn). I can't run the tests because `Property 'bignumber' does not exist on type 'Assertion'`. I can't figure out the issue and I can't find a working example either. chai-bignumber doesn't work either.

I'd appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: The following package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/chai-ethers-bn works like a charm, but it's deprecated.

Comment: The easy but verbose solution is to convert the bignumbers to strings before comparing them. That could work for you if you don't want to install anything else. Alternatively, you could try the `@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle` plugin, that adds some chai matchers, including one for comparing big numbers.

Comment: My [Hardhat-based template](https://github.com/paulrberg/solidity-template) comes pre-configured with Hardhat and Waffle, which makes comparing BigNumbers a breeze.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same error and solve it casting the `BigNumber` into `Number`.

```
  const contractBalance = await ethers.provider.getBalance(contract.address);
  const ownerBalance = await ethers.provider.getBalance(owner.address);

  expect(Number(contractBalance)).to.be.greaterThan(0);

  await contract.connect(owner).withdraw();

  const contractBalanceAfterTxn = await ethers.provider.getBalance(
    contract.address
  );
  const ownerBalanceAfterTxn = await ethers.provider.getBalance(
    owner.address
  );

  expect(Number(contractBalanceAfterTxn)).to.be.equal(0);
  expect(Number(ownerBalanceAfterTxn)).to.be.greaterThan(
    Number(ownerBalance)
  );
```

> contractBalanceAfterTxn BigNumber { value: "0" }

> ownerBalance BigNumber { value: "9996943908220612206777" }

> ownerBalanceAfterTxn BigNumber { value: "9997943866356142795098" }

> ✔ should withdraw if i'm the contract owner (942ms)

> ✔ should fail if i'm not the contract owner (233ms)

Comment: Awesome and straightforward. Up voted.

Comment: Number is a float. If your BigNumber value is bigger than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`, storing it in a number will lose precision and/or fail. MAX_SAFE_INTEGER is 16 digits, 18 digit decimal tokens are ubiquitous, tread carefully. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER

Answer (score 4):

The `ethereum-waffle` package does this very well.

To use it add this to your `hardhat.config.ts`:

```
import chai from "chai";
import { solidity } from "ethereum-waffle";

chai.use(solidity);
```

Then in your tests you can directly compare ethers.js BigNumber values:

```
expect(await token.balanceOf(wallet.address)).to.equal(993);
```

See [ethereum-waffle docs](https://ethereum-waffle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/matchers.html) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

Going through the **ethers** github, I saw this solution:

```
let num = ethers.BigNumber.from(12);
const INTEREST_RATE = 12;
assert(num.eq(ethers.BigNumber.from(INTEREST_RATE)));
```

Explanation: the *eq()* TypeScript function is in https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/blob/master/packages/bignumber/src.ts/bignumber.ts#L156

The normal **assert** works for numbers, but **not for BigNumbers**

```
assert.equal(1, 1);           // equals

assert.equal(num, ethers.BigNumber.from(INTEREST_RATE));   // not equals
```

Answer (score 3):

Here I have a cleaner approach for future readers :

```
expect(await contract.bigNumFunc()).to.equal(ethers.utils.parseUnits("1000", 18));
```

**contract** is the contract that you have deployed.

**bigNumFunc** is a function in your solidity contract that returns a big number, it can be `balanceOf` or any other function.

**Notice** the `ethers.utils.parseUnits` is expecting first argument as `string` and the second argument is number of decimal points.

Answer (score 0):

It is part of the `ethers` library. Here is a simple hardhat task that prints the account and their eth balance:

```
import { Signer } from '@ethersproject/abstract-signer';
import { BigNumber, ethers } from 'ethers';
import { task } from 'hardhat/config';
import { TASK_ACCOUNTS } from './task-names';

task(TASK_ACCOUNTS, 'Prints the list of accounts and their balances', async (_taskArgs, hre) => {
  const accounts: Signer[] = await hre.ethers.getSigners();

  for (const account of accounts) {
    const address: string = await account.getAddress();
    const balance: BigNumber = await hre.ethers.provider.getBalance(address);
    const eth = ethers.utils.formatEther(balance);
    console.log(address, eth);
  }
});
```